# How can I use Devise methods in my ConnectionAdapter callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a rails 5.1 app that's using Devise to handle authentication with my `User` model. This app has an Oracle database backend that requires setting a system context variable with the logged-in user prior to executing any queries, so I was hoping to do that in the `:checkout` callback for the ConnectionAdapter.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :log_user

  ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::OracleEnhancedAdapter.set_callback :checkout, :after do

    # Would like to get the logged-in user's username here so I can apply 
    # it to the oracle sys_context.

    # The below throws "undefined method 'user_signed_in?'"
    username = current_user.username if user_signed_in?

  end

  def log_user
    # When in this method, user_signed_in? and current_user work fine.
    puts "User is #{current_user.username}" if user_signed_in?
  end
end
```

The `user_signed_in?` method isn't found when run in the `:checkout` callback block, though it's generally available in the controller.  Why?

Also, `current_user` within the block seems to evaluate to the `current_user` method defined within the ConnectionAdapter rather than the one defined by Devise. How can I get access to Devise's `current_user`?

How can I use these Devise-provided methods from within this callback?

Comment: The problem with your code is your code block is running in `ApplicationController` class context

Comment: Hmm.  I don't understand.  I think I want it to be running in the `ApplicationController` context but `self` is an `OracleEnhancedAdapter` here inside the callback block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `checkout` callback, at the point that it's executed, it has no connection to the controller context.  The fact that you've defined it here in your `ApplicationController` is irrelevant to the context it's actually executed in.

You will need to set the connection option in the `before_action` so you're running in the controller context.  Something like:

```
before_action :set_user_context

def set_user_context
  if current_user
    ApplicationRecord.connection.execute "DBMS_SESSION.SET_CONTEXT('whatever', 'goes', 'here', '#{current_user.username}')"
  end
end
```

...or something like that.  Note that you might want to add a `checkin` callback to clear the value when the connection is finished with.

Btw, I answered a nearly identical question a few days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54837596/152786  Different commands though, but might help.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense. I had tried this in a before_action, and it seemed to work fine. But then I thought I should use the checkout callback to make sure that all connections in use from the pool had this sys_context applied. Is it really sufficient to just call execute like that, since this query will get executed against only one of the connections in the pool?

Comment: Rails sticks with the one connection for the duration of the request, so yes.

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: I'd just like to add that while "normally"-speaking, there is a unique thread (which means unique connection) per request in Rails, because Chris specifically asked "make sure that all connections in use from the pool had this sys_context applied", then I am compelled to add a bit that it's only true insofar as in the execution flow of the request, it did not open up/ fork a new Thread. See my [repl code](https://repl.it/@jrpolidario1/WheatStrikingBrowsers?language=rails&folderId=), and see application_controller.rb, and then "fork it", then click "run", then refresh the page.

Comment: ^ You'll notice that the main thread is always the same `Connection` object, while inside the forked thread, it's a different `Connection` object. From what I observed and understood, each time you/Rails-internal accesses ActiveRecord/DB code, Rails first checks if the "current executing" thread already has a connection checked-out, and if not yet, then it checkouts a connection from the pool(or creates if all current available connections are in use if not yet max).This is why the "forked thread" has a different Connection object because there was no Connection check-outed yet for that Thread